# How to save image file in BMP format?

Tags: android, image, bitmap, save, bmp

the following code compress my image or it is not a BMP file:

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(imagefile);

bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
fos.flush();
fos.close();
```

How can I save my image in BMP format?

Comment: You should tell us why you think you need a BMP format file. This is a old, heavy, severely windows typed format. What is it you are trying to do ?

Comment: I'm curious, why do you think you need a BMP file? PNG is superior in almost every respect.

Comment: @Yahel :-?????? strange question. think that somebody needs for compatiballity with another system.

Comment: @Meehman : The question is not that strange :) Whenever someone asks for something that does not exists although the Android platform is used by hundreds of thousands of developers, you have to ask yourself if the problem is not that the feature does not exists but rather why you think you need it when thousands other developers don't :) You 'think' that its for someone who needs it, aks them the same question I asked you and you might be surprised by the fact that they don't need it. They just don't know :D They could need it though so ask but I bet they don't :)

Comment: Answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22909429/android-save-a-bitmap-to-bmp-file-format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no built-in encoder for BMP according to [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html) reference. BMP not being an overly complex format, it probably wouldn't be rocket science to write/find a Java implementation.

Comment: It's up to you - it depends how important BMP is to you. You could convert it outside of Android, e.g. on a server that it's saved to. It's not impossible, just not something that's built in to the API for easy use.

Answer (score -2):

Hey just give the name to .bmp

Do this:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
_bitmapScaled.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 40, bytes);

//you can create a new file name "test.BMP" in sdcard folder.
File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                        + File.separator + "**test.bmp**")
```

it'll sound that IM JUST FOOLING AROUND but try it once it'll get saved in bmp format..Cheers

Comment: Changing the file extension doesn't actually make it s bitmap image. It just makes it a png with a .bmp file extension.